# Glassdoor Web Scrape With Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the rating trend data that is displayed in the bottom-left chart of the link below but cannot seem to figure out a way to get to it. I am worried this is because it is embedded as a picture so the data is not accessible but thought I would check.

Added the code I stitched together but I only get the axis values.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

https://www.glassdoor.com/Reviews/Netflix-Reviews-E11891.htm#trends-overallRating

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from time import sleep
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.common import action_chains, keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import numpy as np
import sys
import re
import warnings

options = Options()
options.headless = True


driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'PATH',options=options)
driver.get('https://www.glassdoor.com/Reviews/Netflix-Reviews-E11891.htm#trends-overallRating')

trend_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="DesktopTrendChart"]')[0]
trend = trend_element.text
print(trend)
```

Comment: you're right it looks like that data is rendered in an `svg` image, but it may be possible to extract values from the svg data. Any idea how you would want the data output to be represented?

Comment: Honestly I will take whatever I can get but if I could get the dates and values next to each other it would be a huge help. Really just looking for the values at each date.

Comment: Ya that's tricky. You can get the dates as I see that in there, but the corresponding values you'll have to do some work. The line is drawn by x and y coordinates (which is there), but then you'd have to scale that in some way. And even then, it's looking like it would be estimates. I think it'll be really hard/complex to work out/to do, but not impossible to get something relatively close

Comment: Actually, after thinking about it some more, I’ll give it a shot tomorrow when I have some time to work it out. I have a few ideas I could try that actually shouldn’t be too difficult to pull that info out.

Comment: Really appreciate it, no rush and totally fine if it is not possible, more curious than anything. Go Bears!

Comment: not programtic solution, may be solve your problem [WebPlotDegitizer](https://automeris.io/WebPlotDigitizer/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was originally having a go at it using BeautifulSoup.

I was able to pull out all the coordinates of the corresponding values (which I did successfully do). Took about an hour or so to find where it was all located, extract it, get into a nice, tidy dataframe.

For the next step, I was going to convert the x and y coordinates to the corresponding x and y labels, then interpolate to create a more granular set of data (which I had not attempted yet). I was anticipating this would take about another hour or so.

I did a little more research prior to doing that and found an interesting article [here](https://onlinejournalismblog.com/2017/05/10/how-to-find-data-behind-chart-map-using-inspector/).

After reading it, and then going back to the orginal problem, was able to do this in a) less line of code, b) without BeautifulSoup, and c) took me about 5-10 minutes to do, and d) I learned something new.

So read over that link, check out the code, and this should get you what you need.

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.glassdoor.co.uk/api/employer/11891-rating.htm?dataType=trend&category=overallRating&locationStr=&jobTitleStr=&filterCurrentEmployee=false'

with requests.Session() as se:
    se.headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Language": "en"
    }
    response = se.get(url)

data = json.loads(response.text)

results = pd.DataFrame()
results['date'], results['rating'] = data['dates'], data['employerRatings']
```

**Output:**

```
print (results)
          date  rating
0   2018/12/30  3.66104
1   2018/12/30  3.66311
2   2018/11/25  3.69785
3   2018/10/28  3.73478
4    2018/9/30  3.68311
5    2018/8/26  3.69093
6    2018/7/29  3.70312
7    2018/6/24  3.74851
8    2018/5/27  3.67543
9    2018/4/29  3.67500
10   2018/3/25  3.62248
11   2018/2/25  3.73467
12   2018/1/28  3.70791
13  2017/12/31  3.72217
14  2017/11/26  3.69733
15  2017/10/29  3.61443
16   2017/9/24  3.47046
17   2017/8/27  3.46511
18   2017/7/30  3.46711
19   2017/6/25  3.48164
20   2017/5/28  3.52925
21   2017/4/30  3.46825
22   2017/3/26  3.46874
23   2017/2/26  3.52620
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, I really appreciate your help

Comment: superrr answer!!! @chitown88, learnt something +1 , one doubt popping in mind that is how did you got that URL in your answer, it is different than one in question

Comment: @Dev read the link of the article I reference. I used the “Inspect” and just looked through the responses until I found what I was looking for. Takes some detective work.

Comment: It seems that this no long works. Got an error:     
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: I just tried it and works fine. What country you access it from?

Comment: I think I now know the reason. My Url is in a different format. Can I construct a Url in your format based on the company ID? E.g. This is for Apple: https://www.glassdoor.ca/Overview/Working-at-Apple-EI_IE1138.11,16.htm.  is 1138.11,16 the company ID for Apple? Thanks.

Comment: I checked. I believe the company ID is 1138. Is there a way to get the company ID based on the company name? I have thousands of companies I would like to get the employer ratings. I also have the website addresses of these companies.

Comment: I’ll take a look at it tomorrow and get back to you.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: the canada site is a bit tricky. not sure it's able to access the api. you may need selenium for this one.

Comment: also does look like you can pull company id, but just for the "major" ones. I didn't see a way to post a query that would return the specific id. Does it need to be through the .ca? can you use .com?

Comment: I'm directed to the Canada site automatically. I can't log in to the US site with the same email.

Comment: ahhh. ok. Tricky then. I'll have to look over it again after the weekend. In the meantime, I'd say look into automating the process with selenium.

Comment: Yes, I will. Thank you.

Comment: I wrote some scripts using selenium that allows me to collect the current ratings. Still don't know how to get the trend data for individual ratings such as culture & values, Diversity & Inclusion, and even CEO Approval, which also has a trend.  I noticed that if I replaced the employer ID with that of another company in your url, I can get the trend data for the overall rating of that company. Do you know how to get the trend data for other types of ratings? Thank you!

Comment: I figured it out after reading the article you provided. Thank you very much.