# How can I scrape data from a graph with python

Tags: python, graph, web-scraping

Hi I'm trying to get all the data from a graph for this site [here](https://www.plus500.co.za/Instruments/CL?searchTerm=oil)

I don't have that much codding experience but I have tried getting the source for the graph put only got the live data that updates the graph [here](https://www.plus500.co.za/api/LiveData/FeedUpdate?instrumentId=10), I got a bunch of data using the inspect tool on chrome at class="highcharts-series highcharts-series-0" but I'm not sure if that is what I'm looking for, I have searched and tried different ways but nothing I came across worked for me.

```
from requests import get
import time


url = 'https://www.plus500.co.za/Instruments/CL?searchTerm=oil'
user_agent = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/0.0'}
response = get(url, headers=user_agent)
print(response.text)
```

I got the text from the website and I have looked at all the links I have no idea what I'm looking for.

Comment: Hi, any idea of how you want the data output formatted? Not sure what the axes of the chart are, but would it be price, quantity, or dates?

Comment: I looked at some videos of sentdex and he used matplotlibs so data I can plot on matplotlibs

Comment: If you plot in matplotlib, what would be the X,Y axes ? Using the answer to this question 
([Glassdoor Web Scrape With Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54046254/glassdoor-web-scrape-with-selenium#comment94928512_54046254)) I'm able to get a list two values like `1546937100000,  48.64`.

Comment: I'm looking for the entire graph from start to end. The format I think will the time and the price but a plus would be to get data from candelsticks like entry points, low points, high points and exit points

Comment: Oh ok I see. thanks.